# Compare two PostgreSQL columns with strings separated by slash "/" or parentheses "( )"

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, string-comparison

I am fairly new to Rails/PostgreSQL and just got stuck on this seemingly simple problem.

How do I compare string values of two columns when one column contains multiple string values of the same thing in different languages separated by either slash "/" or parentheses "( )"?

```
ID |    Drink #1   |     Drink #2
 1 |      Water    |   Agua/Water/Eau
 2 |    Magnesium  | Magnesio (Magnesium)
```

I am primarily looking for a PostgreSQL query to display in the view "Both Drink #1 and Drink #2 contain Water and Magnesium", but I am also wondering if there could be other ways using a controller (C of MVC). I searched for relevant Rails Gems, but no success after many hours.

Thank you all!

Comment: Isn't it just search for sub-string? Search if Drink #1 exists in Drink #2?

Comment: what is your expected output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply check whether `drink1` is a substring of `drink2`:

```
select *
from drinks
where drink2 like format('%%%s%%', drink1);

 id |  drink1   |        drink2
----+-----------+----------------------
  1 | Water     | Agua/Water/Eau
  2 | Magnesium | Magnesio (Magnesium)
(2 rows)
```

Check whether `drink1` is strictly a part of a `drink2` divided by `/`:

```
select *
from drinks
where drink1 = any(string_to_array(drink2, '/'));

 id | drink1 |     drink2
----+--------+----------------
  1 | Water  | Agua/Water/Eau
(1 row)
```

Check whether `drink2` contains `drink1` in brackets:

```
select *
from drinks
where drink2 like format('%%(%s)%%', drink1);

 id |  drink1   |        drink2
----+-----------+----------------------
  2 | Magnesium | Magnesio (Magnesium)
(1 row)
```

Queries #2 and #3 in one:

```
select *
from drinks
where drink1 = any(string_to_array(drink2, '/'))
or drink2 like format('%%(%s)%%', drink1);

 id |  drink1   |        drink2
----+-----------+----------------------
  1 | Water     | Agua/Water/Eau
  2 | Magnesium | Magnesio (Magnesium)
(2 rows)
```

---

**Update 2015-09-02**

You have two forms of syntax in the column `drink2`. 
The forms can be regarded as *symmetric* (with slash) and *asymmetric* (with brackets).
You should transform *asymmetric* items into *symmetric* ones.
You can use functions [`replace()` and `translate()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-string.html):

```
select *, replace(translate(drink2, '()', '/'), ' /', '/')
from drinks

 id |  drink1   |        drink2        |      replace
----+-----------+----------------------+--------------------
  1 | Water     | Agua/Water/Eau       | Agua/Water/Eau
  2 | Magnesium | Magnesio (Magnesium) | Magnesio/Magnesium
(2 rows)
```

and your query may look like this:

```
select *
from drinks
where drink1 = any(string_to_array(replace(translate(drink2, '()', '/'), ' /', '/'), '/'));
```

Comment: Actually, one more question regarding the brackets: what if Drink 2 (second column) contains 'Magnesium (Magnesio)' - i.e. the string value to be compared is not inside brackets? I am not sure substring query can be used since such query would result in false positives in cases like 'Magnesium Sulfate,' which is not the same as 'Magnesium'.